# Using the iPhone SDK, can I programmatically get a list of the applications/games on a users iPhone/iPod touch?

Tags: iphone, arrays, app-store

I would like to be able to pull the list of apps and games the user has and present it to them, or launch one of them.  I'm guessing that Apple doesn't provide this capability in the iphone sdk.  Still, I'd like to know how to do it and still be eligible for the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct Apple does not provide this in the iPhone SDK, therefore you cannot do this and get your app into the app store.

Answer (score 0):

If the application has a published URL spec (i.e. Google Maps, Mail, ...) then you can launch the applicaiton via the URL launching spec.

But if the given game / application doesn't support the URL launching spec, then you have no way to launch it from your application. I also believe you cannot determine if an app is installed via the URL spec, only launch the application.

Check out the "URL types" reference for Info.PLIST.